# How to change security group for existing amazon EC2 ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ip, restrict

I have tried to change the instance security group by right click and then "change security groups", but it's grayed out.

***Update:-***
I have a rails application and I want to give the response from the particular Ip(ex: 12.123.12.456) requests, if the request from that IP(ex: 12.123.12.456) then give the response otherwise drop the request.
so I am trying to change the security group in AWS.

what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your instance is in EC2-Classic. You can not change security group for EC2-classic instance. You should first migrate your instance to EC2-VPC environment and then you can change security group as and when necessary.

P.S: Better give proper description for your question. With the question posted as above, one can only assume and answer unless you provide the accurate information.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can go on your all instance, then click on your specific instance then scroll down and check the description for that instance and click on your old security instance and also you can change security group